# i writing a besic code for finding premium customer who ordered quantity is equal or more then 5 and amount in also more then 20rs in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
customers_data = {
  'Ben10': [22, 30, 11, 17, 15, 52, 27, 12],
  'Sameer': [5, 17, 30, 33, 40, 22, 26, 10, 11, 45],
  'Zeeshan': [22, 30, 11, 5, 17, 30, 6, 57]
}
var cus = Object.keys(customers_data);
var count = 0;
for (var j = 0; j < cus.length; j++) {
  console.log(cus[j]);
  for (var i = 0; i < customers_data.cus[j].length; i++) {
    if (customers_data.cus[j][i] > 20) {
      count++;
      colsole.log(cus[j][i])
    }
  }
  if (count >= 5) {
    console.log(cus[j] + "is prime customer")
  } else {
    console.log('count of order is' + count)
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: So is the expected output here ?

Comment: The count variable is applied to all 3 customers and the final console log (outside the for loops) is only being applied to the final customer. I'm guessing you meant to nest the count and conditional `console.log()` statements for each customer, which can be done by instantiating `count` inside the outer `for` loop (the one with `j`), as well as including the conditional `console.log()` in the same loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the count variable, at least the initialization with zero inside of the outer loop.

The second propblem, you need to access the property with the value in bracket notation ([property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)).

```
customers_data[cus[j]]
```

```js
var customers_data = { Ben10: [22, 30, 11, 17, 15, 52, 27, 12], Sameer: [5, 17, 30, 33, 40, 22, 26, 10, 11, 45], Zeeshan: [22, 30, 11, 5, 17, 30, 6, 57] },
    cus = Object.keys(customers_data);

for (var j = 0; j < cus.length; j++) {
    let count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < customers_data[cus[j]].length; i++) {
        if (customers_data[cus[j]][i] > 20) count++;
    }
    console.log('count of order is ' + count)
    if (count >= 5) {
        console.log(cus[j] + " is prime customer")
    }
}
```